# Trouble querying mongo dates with PHP library

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to get all documents that match a certain date range. I've created the query in the Mongo CLI successfully, but I'm having trouble translating it to the PHP Mongo library (I just upgraded to PHP 7, so working with the new driver/library is taking some getting used to).

Why do I get back results in the CLI, but nothing in my code?

```
$search = [];
if (isset($_GET['days'])) {
    $days = explode(',', $_GET['days']);
    foreach ($days as $day) {
        $date = $dates[$day];
        $start = new DateTime($date, new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
        $start = new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime($start);
        $end = new DateTime($date, new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
        $end->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day'));
        $end = new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime($end);
        $search[] = [
            'date.start' => [
                '$gte' => $start,
                '$lte' => $end
            ]
        ];
    }
}
$rEvents = $mongo->events->find($search);
```

`$dates` translates the word day to the date it corresponds to. When I check the DateTime objects created, they're correct, but still, no results come back. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: What's version of MongoDB driver you use? Also there is the extra brackets in the query, it should be $search['date.start'] = [

Comment: Not sure about the driver, but the library is 1.1. But you're right. My intention was to basically do an "or", but my logic was bad. I know how to fix it, thanks. If you want to actually put in an answer, I'll mark it as correct to give you credit.

Answer (score 3):

I worked a bit untill I found out how to do it(it works with php 7 new mongo drivers).

```
my db="TEST"
my collection="colUser"
```

So let's start.

1) First we have to instatiate the driver php  as following :

## The CODE

```
 $database=new MongoDB\Driver\Manager;
   // Instantiate the php 7 mongo library
 //2)Prepare the date (mongo uses miliseconds from 1970 not seconds 
//like php)
$date1="2015-01-02";
$date1=new DateTime($date1);
$date1=new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDatetime($date1->getTimeStamp() * 
1000);//Transforming into miliseconds

$date2="2016-06-01";
$date2=new DateTime($date2);
$date2=new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDatetime($date2->getTimeStamp() * 1000);// 
//Transforming second date into ms
//Prepare the array to select time  from $date1 to $date2 from mongo db
$array=array("date"=>array(
                     "\$gte"=>$date1,
                     "\$lt"=>$date2 ));                      
$query=new MongoDB\Driver\Query($array);// Preparing the query
$rows=$database->executeQuery("TEST.colUser",$query);// Getting the data into 
//object $rows
// NOW WHE HAVE TO PRINT THE DATE`s THAT WE FOUND IN THE INTERVAL FROM THE 
//COLLECTIONS
foreach($rows as $k=>$v){// each object $v represents objects from one row
  foreach($v as $key=>$value){// each object from one row
                 if($key=="date"){// "date" is the index time from collection
                     foreach($value as $t=>$time){// $value is an object and 
//it needs an foreach "[milliseconds]->time"
                             $time=$time / 1000; //transform from ms into 
//seconds
                     }
                           echo date("Y-m-d",(int)$time);//finally we are 
//echoing the time in YEAR-MONTH-DAY     
                           echo "<br>";                
                   }
         }
}
```

Comment: OMG dude, i have been looking for something that works for entirely way to long! Thanks so much!

$date1=new DateTime($date1);  infront of the UTCDatetime line makes it all work. Plus the array within an array in the WHERE clause! I was using an object for the "gte" and "lt" and PHP didn't respond with an error, just no data. Thanks again!

Comment: I was missing that the PHP timestamp is in seconds but I need to pass it in ms. Thanks for that.